# AngularJS no module : myApp

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to run a basic AngularJS example, but it is throwing no module : module name Error.
Following is the jsFiddle Link:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input ng-model="msg" />
    <p>
        {{msg}}
    </p>
</body>

// the main (app) module
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

// add a controller
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "hello world";
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8nf7asg7/

Comment: Must be the fiddle, works fine in jsbin http://jsbin.com/sibusuquja/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2):

The problem was your JS file is not getting loaded, just change from "onLoad" to WrapinHead

[image]
Working [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/8nf7asg7/6/)

Comment: Yep, it is just a fiddle bug.